# Multiple smooths for same predictor in GAM

Tags: biostatistics, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

Is it appropriate to include two similar smooths of the same predictor variable in a GAM model?

**An example:** Assume I have count data relating to the birth of rabbits across Australia over a 15 year period. I want to look to see if there is a repeating annual Australia-wide pattern in the birth of rabbits but I am also interested to know if there are repeating annual patterns at the state-level. I fit the below model:

```
gam(CountRabbitBirth ~ s(Month, bs = "cc", k = 12) + 
               s(Month, bs = "cc", k = 12, by = State), 
             family = nb(), 
             method = "REML", 
             knots = knots,
             select = TRUE)
```

In the above model `s(Month, bs = "cc", k = 12)` represents a cyclic cubic regression spline to model the overarching Australia-wide annual pattern in the count of rabbit births. `s(Month, bs = "cc", k = 12, by = State)` then represents a cyclic cubic regression spline to model state-specific annual patterns in the count of rabbit births.

Is this model appropriate and justified? The same predictor, `Month`, is being included in two similar smooths, but these two smooths are each testing a different question.

If this is not appropriate how would one test for these two different patterns, that are present at different spatial scales, in the same model? Can this be done in the same model?

Comment: Colleagues and I have [written extensively about this](https://doi.org/10.7717/peerj.6876). I can expand a bit on this in an answer later. In summary; yes this is justified. But... you can very often run into identifiability issues with smooths like this, especially when the indidivual state level curves are similar to the "global" smoother. You most likely need to add `m=1` to the `by` smooth, which will have the effect of penalising any deviation from a flat function (i.e. deviation from the "global" smooth).